# Objective-c stringByAppendingString return string nil

Tags: objective-c

I have this code here, basically it takes an array goes through each item and adds it to a string with a comma at the end and after the loop, remove the last comma:

```
NSString *areaDescriptionWSpaceCharacters = nil;

    for(NSString *item in areaDescription)
    {
        [areaDescriptionWSpaceCharacters stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@,", item]];
    }

    areaDescriptionWSpaceCharacters = [areaDescriptionWSpaceCharacters substringToIndex:[areaDescriptionWSpaceCharacters length] - 1];
```

but areaDescriptionWSpaceCharacters returns `nil`. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are appending a string to `nil`. You need to initialize the string to an empty string first.

```
NSString *areaDescriptionWSpaceCharacters = @"";
```

In this case you might consider using `NSMutableString`.

```
NSMutableString *areaDescriptionWSpaceCharacters = [NSMutableString string];

for (NSString *item in areaDescription) {
    if (areaDescriptionWSpaceCharacters.length > 0) {
        [areaDescriptionWSpaceCharacters appendString:@","];
    }

    [areaDescriptionWSpaceCharacters appendString:item];
}
```

or directly

```
NSString *areaDescriptionWSpaceCharacters = [areaDescription componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

(this task is so common there is a special method for it!)

Answer (score 1):

Your first line itself is the culprit here. You have not initialized the NSString yet so it will always be nil.

```
 NSString *areaDescriptionWSpaceCharacters;
```

or

```
NSString *areaDescriptionWSpaceCharacters = @"";
```

or

```
NSString *areaDescriptionWSpaceCharacters = [[NSString alloc] init];
```